# Radio Button Model returns undefined value when a save button is clicked

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-model

I have 2 radio buttons, which I assigned values of '0' and '1' respectively. I need to get the value when I click my Save Button but It returns an Undefined value. Here is my code. What could be my problem?

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in recruleData">
   <td>
       {{item.package_name}}
   </td>
   <td>
       <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="radio.selectedProductBlock"
            value="0"  >A<br/>
       <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="radio.selectedProductBlock"
            value="1" > B
    </td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="radioValue();">Save</a>
</tr>
```

my JS Code

```
$scope.selectedProductBlock;
$scope.radioValue= function(){    
   alert($scope.selectedProductBlock);    
}
```

Comment: you need define radio variable first. https://angularjs-rfdf9b.stackblitz.io

Comment: I did it and the value returns ok the problem now is thet my radio button is under an ng-repeat and the checked displays are not working well. I checked the lower radio button but the lower radio button is on the upper set has been checked

Comment: you may need use ng-value for each radio button

Comment: I used ng-value already but the selected display in my UI seems to be confused, Its selecting other radiobutton on click

Comment: you need show your js code

Comment: @PerryPan I updated my question already

Comment: Show the `ng-repeat` in your code.

Comment: @georgeawg Updated my code already Thanks

Comment: if you have multiline of data, the radio button's value is the same. so assume you checked the second line, maybe your first line radio button may changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a variable of type boolean inside the object radio,

```
$scope.radio = {};
$scope.radio.selectedProductBlock = false;
```

and then

And radioValue function

```
$scope.radioValue = function(){
   console.log($scope.radio.selectedProductBlock);
}
```

Comment: I did it and the value returns ok the problem now is thet my radio button is under an ng-repeat and the checked displays are not working well. I checked the lower radio button but the lower radio button is on the upper set has been checked

Comment: if this is inside a ng-repeat, you need to have variable in each object you are using in ng-repeat

Comment: how can I do that? can ypu please help me?

Answer (score -1):

According to your requirement, you need to define radio object in recruleData 
 each record

Ex :

```
 $scope.recruleData  = [
      {"package_name" : "package1", "radio":{"selectedProductBlock":""}},
      {"package_name" : "package1", "radio":{"selectedProductBlock":""}},
    ]
```

And radioValue function

```
 $scope.radioValue= function(item){    
   alert(item.radio.selectedProductBlock);    
  }
```

In addition, you need to give a unique name for each row radio button groups. You can simply achieve that append `$index` to your radio button name.

HTML Code

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Package</th>
      <th>Actioins</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in recruleData">
   <td>
       {{item.package_name}}
   </td>
   <td>
       <input type="radio" name="radio_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.radio.selectedProductBlock"
            value="0"  >A<br/>
       <input type="radio" name="radio_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.radio.selectedProductBlock"
            value="1" > B
    </td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="radioValue(item);">Save</a></td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Working  [JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/DushyanthaRDDK/5DMjt/20578/)

Comment: I did it and the value returns ok the problem now is thet my radio button is under an ng-repeat and the checked displays are not working well. I checked the lower radio button but the lower radio button is on the upper set has been checked

Comment: If you want each row with separate radio buttons and values,  you need to define radio object in recruleData each record.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your requirements.